# Downloading a mp3 file from another server to my server

Tags: javascript, node.js, mp3

I have a nodejs server where I use a GET request to receive the contents of a mp3 file. Then I use writefile to copy the contents into a mp3 file. The problem is that the mp3 file is broken or something because  I can't play it with any mp3 player, but writefile worked successfully.

```
 request(options, function(error,response,body) {

    var path = "C://Users/foo/pop.mp3";
    var wstream = fs.createWriteStream(path);
    wstream.write(body);

    wstream.end();


    res.status(200).send(body);
  });
```

Comment: 1) open the mp3 in notepad to ensure its not an HTML error page 2) what is body and how is it populated?

Comment: the body is the mp3 gibberish that looks something like this "a��qv Cı�Je���vM��!زe�995��K��� �(n_ndL1@�,8M�@<�2&ĉDz��<�"

Comment: Do you think it might be some character encoding error?

Answer (score 0):

Your `body` parameter doesn't just contain the straight body, so when you're calling `wstream.write(body)` you're just writing the `body` object and not the actual data.

Make the following change

```
wstream.write(body.Body.data)
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue by piping the response straight to the file and setting the content-type header for the request as ISO-8859-1.